# Automatic input before next click input

Tags: java, android

I have difficulties when enter the number, where I should to enter the click number one by one.

Example picture

[image: Click Here]

I want to input column 1 is finished it will automatically click the next column, without me having to click on the second column and so on. so I just clicked on the keyboard number only in my phone.

My xml code :

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/column1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"  />
```

My java code empty :

Maybe someone here can help my problem.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far to get it to work? Have you seen what APIs the `EditText` provides (specifically, the event kind)? Which solutions you've tried, what did you find lacking?

Comment: now I'm trying to repair, maybe you can help me contribute your thoughts

Comment: check this might help [link1](https://github.com/ChaosLeung/PinView)

Comment: @Mohammed Alaa, that fine but should add implementation, if there is a normal way do you know whether?

Comment: @Aing Macan are the number of edittext fixed ?

Comment: @Mohammed Alaa, 4 EditText, the link you sent is very useful but I want to use the normal method without adding implementation

Comment: @Aing Macan see this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398692/android-move-cursor-from-one-edittext-to-another-one) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418324/android-move-cursor-from-one-edittext-to-another-one-if-click-any-letter-in-fiel)

Comment: @Mohammed Alaa, ok, I'll try firs

Comment: @Mohammed Alaa, link2 very useful thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Move cursor from one EditText to another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398692/android-move-cursor-from-one-edittext-to-another-one)